# MYSQL combine view of two table having different number of entry records

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am working on WampServer/MySQL,
I found some errors while select query, coz I want to have one view of two tables.. but having different number of entry records. 
Example is given in below:

Table 1 (SALE)

```
 +----+------------+-----------------+-------+
 |ID  | Date       | Description     |Amount |
 +----+------------+-----------------+-------+
 |1   |2014-09-01  | Book Store      | 10000 |
 |2   |2014-09-01  | General Store   | 5000  |
 +----+------------+-----------------+-------+
```

now its query is:

```
select * from sale;
```

Table 2 (Expense)

```
 +----+------------+-----------------+-------+
 |ID  | Date       | Description     |Amount |
 +----+------------+-----------------+-------+
 |1   |2014-09-01  | Hospitality     | 2000  |
 +----+------------+-----------------+-------+
```

and its query is:

```
select * from Expense
```

Now the Query I am running is below:

```
  select Sale.Date,Sale.Description,Expense.Description,Sale.Amount,
  Expense.Amount from sale,expense where Sale.Date ='2014-09-01' and
  Expense.Date='2014-09-01'
```

the result of above query is below:

```
 +------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+---------------+
 | Date       | SaleDescription | ExpenseDescription | SaleAmount | ExpenseAmount |
 +------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+---------------+
 |2014-09-01  | Book Store      | Hospitality        | 10000      | 2000          |
 |2014-09-01  | General Store   | Hospitality        | 5000       | 2000          |
 +------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+---------------+
```

now the problem is that Table 1 (Sale) data is OK, showing all its entries.. but Table 2 (expense) is also showing two entries where as it has only one entry record!

```
select Sale.Date as Date,Sale.Description as SaleDescription,      
null as ExpenseDescription, Sale.Amount as SaleAmount, null as ExpenseAmount
from Sale where Sale.Date ='2014-09-01'
UNION
select Expense.Date as Date, null as SaleDescription,      
Expense.Description as ExpenseDescription, null as SaleAmount, Expense.Amount as 
ExpenseAmount
from Expense where Expense.Date ='2014-09-01';
```

this query told by CodeNewbie results below:

```
 +------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+---------------+
 | Date       | SaleDescription | ExpenseDescription | SaleAmount | ExpenseAmount |
 +------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+---------------+
 |2014-09-01  | Book Store      | NULL               | 10000      | NULL          |
 |2014-09-01  | NULL            | Hospitality        | NULL       | 2000          |
 +------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+---------------+
```

Can anyone help me out through this..?
thanks in advance

Comment: in last query.. it miss the second entry from Sale table!

Comment: Try the updated code. I have used `UNION ALL` now. I think it should work properly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant to create a union of `SALE` and `EXPENSE` but ended up creating a join. You mentioned that the data from *`SALE` is OK*, but that isn't true either.

Refer to [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm) to learn a bit about joins. Your query roughly reads like this:

```
select Sale.Date,Sale.Description,Expense.Description,Sale.Amount,Expense.Amount 
from sale,expense 
where Sale.Date = Expense.Date and
Expense.Date='2014-09-01';
```

This is the syntax for a join much like the one in the example in the above link.

What you need to perform is a `UNION` operation on the rows of both tables. See [this tutorial] on `UNION` operations in MySQL. The query you need is below:

```
select Sale.Date as Date,Sale.Description as SaleDescription,      
null as ExpenseDescription, Sale.Amount as SaleAmount, null as ExpenseAmount
from Sale where Sale.Date ='2014-09-01'
UNION ALL
select Expense.Date as Date, null as SaleDescription,      
Expense.Description as ExpenseDescription, null as SaleAmount, Expense.Amount as ExpenseAmount
from Expense where Expense.Date ='2014-09-01';
```

Comment: dear CodeNewBie... I have updated my question.. kindly have look .. I ran your query.. but it doesnt output the correct result..!!

Comment: okay, that is unexpected behaviour. Can you verify once by just running only the first `select` statement in isolation and see that it returns 2 records?

Comment: `select Sale.Date as Date,Sale.Description as SaleDescription,      
null as ExpenseDescription, Sale.Amount as SaleAmount, null as ExpenseAmount
from Sale where Sale.Date ='2014-09-01'`

Comment: your updated query returns empty result set (0 rows) :(

Comment: Have you tried the query in isolation like I suggested in between?

Comment: running only one select statement on each separate table shows actual record as mentioned in question. but when select is applied to both tables it shows duplicate entry of second table to complete a row (i guess).. where as second table has only one entry\]

Comment: I set up a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cf01/2) and tested my query with the same data you provided. And the results are as expected, with both `UNION` and `UNION ALL`. I don't understand why it isn't working for you.

Comment: is there any relation between their IDs..?? primary or foreign key concept?

Comment: no, there is no relation between their IDs. You can check the table creation code on the left too.

Comment: Thanks buddy... now working properly... sorry I missed something in your query.. thats y it was giving not correct result..!