# MYSQL combine view of two table having different number of entry records in date range

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Referencing to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740880/mysql-combine-view-of-two-table-having-different-number-of-entry-records), which I asked some days ago and got the solution.
and answer was pretty nice.. but now the problem with that is when I am giving range to my table records.. it is not resulting in the way which i want it to result. i.e.
[image]

the pic above is the result of query:

```
SELECT Sale.Date AS Date, Sale.Description AS SaleDescription, "" AS   ExpenseDescription, Sale.Amount AS SaleAmount, "" AS ExpenseAmount
FROM Sale
WHERE Sale.Date >= '2014-09-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT Expense.Date AS Date, "" AS SaleDescription, Expense.Description AS ExpenseDescription, "" AS SaleAmount, Expense.Amount AS ExpenseAmount
FROM Expense
WHERE Expense.Date >= '2014-09-01'
```

when you look at to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740880/mysql-combine-view-of-two-table-having-different-number-of-entry-records) in which query is ran for a particular date.. which gives correct results.. (Proper result).. but when I give it a rang of date it displays record not order by date. like here

it shows all records from one table in a date range.. then displays second tables records in date range.

I want that it should show the records date wise, but not table wise.!

I hope you understand my question, cause my english is not so good.

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to do a sort over the entire results, either by nesting the select within another or by using a temporary table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Tim B said the nesting solution should look probably like this :

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT Sale.Date AS Date, Sale.Description AS SaleDescription, "" AS   ExpenseDescription, Sale.Amount AS SaleAmount, "" AS ExpenseAmount
   FROM Sale
   WHERE Sale.Date >= '2014-09-01'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Expense.Date AS Date, "" AS SaleDescription, Expense.Description AS ExpenseDescription, "" AS SaleAmount, Expense.Amount AS ExpenseAmount
   FROM Expense
   WHERE Expense.Date >= '2014-09-01') AS SaleExpense
ORDER BY
  SaleExpense.Date ASC
```